# AbstractMethodError when accessing Wicket Application (jboss server)

Tags: spring, servlets, jboss, wicket, jboss-4.2.x

The error coming is:

`19:09:30,077 ERROR [[default]] Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.isAsyncStarted()Z`

I have checked several stack overflow posts on this topic, but all refer to "NoClassDefFoundError" for isAsyncStarted()Z. I am at a stand-still because when I try to access localhost:8080/appname/ this exception is thrown.

I read that javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar could be the issue, but I am unsure why my error is different than others.

I know this is pretty vague, but I would imagine someone has encountered this issue w/ wicket servlets.

Am I missing some vital config for using Wicket/Jboss/Spring?
(I can provide additional info if needed)

Full stacktrace:

```
    19:09:30,077 ERROR [[default]] Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.isAsyncStarted()Z
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:234)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You need to upgrade to [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) for servlet API 3 or Tomcat 8 for servlet API 3.1.</del> You **must not** package any servlet API jars in your WAR.

Update:

You can't run it on JBoss AS 4. You need at least JBoss AS 7 or EAP 6 or WildFly 8.

Comment: How do I tell my jboss runtime env. to use Tomcat 8 instead of 7? When setting up my jboss, I just did it through eclipse and clicked create new runtime env. and followed the steps. I did this using JBoss 4.2, but now I'm thinking I should use 7.0? Or, are you telling me I need to manually download Tomcat 8 and run `catalina run` from that directory? I am a little unsure of how to upgrade tomcats used with jboss, so if you could answer that, that would be awesome! @PhilippeMarschall

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I get home from work. Sounds promising though ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Wicket 7 depends on Servlets 3, it seems you have an older version on your classpath.

Comment: Which explicit location are you referring to? The projects class path contains servlet-api-3.1.0.jar and I replaced the servlet-api.jar in my jboss/server/default/lib folder with this jar as well. Where else could I be referencing an older version of the servlet-api?